# Problems with CMD variables

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have 3 `.cmd` scripts

1. VariablesManagement

   ```
   SET numCamerasInMigration=0
   ```
2. NameCameras

   ```
   FOR /L %%c IN (1,1,43) DO ( SET /a numCamerasInMigration=%numCamerasInMigration%+1) 
   echo %numCamerasInMigration%
   ```
3. RunPrograms

   ```
   echo %numCamerasInMigration%
   CALL "VariableManagementTMB" :SET_VARIBALES
   echo %numCamerasInMigration%
   CALL "NameCameras"
   echo %numCamerasInMigration%
   PAUSE>nul
   ```

---

***Current Output***:

> RuningPrograms
>
> echo is disabled (BEFORE SET VARIABLES)
>
> 0 (AFTER SET VARIABLES)
>
> 43 (IN NAMECAMERA)
>
> 0 (WHEN HE RETURN TO RUNPROGRAMS)
>
> pause

---

***My Question:***

Why the variable changes value in the cmd namecameras, but when returning to the cmd runprograms sige with its "initial" value?

Comment: Replace `SET /a numCamerasInMigration=%numCamerasInMigration%+1` by `SET /a numCamerasInMigration+=1`, or enable and use [delayed variable expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) like `SET /a numCamerasInMigration=!numCamerasInMigration!+1`... Anyway, what is the point of adding 1 for 43 times, why not simply adding 43?

Answer (score 1):

Try `NameCameras` with this code, do not change the other scripts.

```
@echo off
for /L %%c IN (1,1,43) do (
set /a numCamerasInMigration=numCamerasInMigration+1
)
echo %numCamerasInMigration%
```

Which by running `RunPrograms` gives me:

RuningPrograms

> echo is disabled (before set)
>
> 0 (after set)
>
> 43 (echo in nameCamera)
>
> 43 (final echo in RunPrograms)

***Hint**:* consider `set /?`

Any non-numeric strings in the expression are treated as environment variable names whose values are converted to numbers before using them.
If an environment variable name is specified but is not defined in the current environment, then a value of zero is used.  This allows you to do arithmetic with environment variable values without having to type all those % signs to get their values.

Also, just as a side note, consider adding `@echo off` top of each script to eliminate echoing actual commands.

Comment: The for /l loop doesn't make sense, it will increase the var `numCamerasInMigration` by 43, why not simple use instead `Set /A numCamerasInMigration+=43` ?

Comment: @LotPings That is not really the issue here. the OP is expecting the result to be returned to the original script and it is not.

Comment: Agreed, but the real issue is delayexpansion respective the missing of it, when using a var in percent signs inside a (code block) it is expanded at parse time not run time.

Comment: @lotpings. Yes but notice that % signs are not needed when running `set /a`

Comment: @LotPings, I agree it makes no sense to use a `FOR /L` to get the variable to 43.  They could just a set a variable to 43.  They are either obfuscating some code or they just really want to do it that way.

Comment: @squashman, yes and I also agree, but I answered based on the issue which is that the variable is not returned to the original launched batch. You will however notice that delayed expansion is not needed here.